# i faced with :Error 2 error C3861: 'fx': identifier not found

Tags: c++

i'm not much familiar to define function in cpp, but as usual i defined mine like:

```
#include<iostream>;
#include<Windows.h>;
using namespace std;
int main(){

int n;
int power;

//f(x) = x^power-n=0
cout << "please enter number of root: " << endl;
cin >> power;
cout << "what number you want to get root: "<< endl;
cin >> n;
double x = 2;//it's the first x0 that newton algorithm needs

for (int i = 0; i<20000 ;i++)
{
   //f(x) = x^power-n=0 , f'(x) = 2*x //fx:x^power
   x = x - (fx(power,x) - n)/dif(power,x);
}
cout << "answer is " << x << endl;
return 0;

}

double fx (int power,int x){
for (int i = 1; i<power; i++)
{
    x = x*x;    
}
return x;
}

double dif (int power,int x){
//f(x) = x^power-n=0 -> f'(x) = power * x^(power-1)
if(power>1)
{
     for(int i = 1; i<power-1 ;i++){
     x = x*x;
     }
x = x*power;
return x;
}
return 1;
}
```

and i faced with 2 errors that say:
Error 2 error C3861: 'fx': identifier not found
Error 4 error C3861: 'dif': identifier not found
so what should i do?

Comment: Are you familiar with function prototypes?

Comment: In C++, you need to have something declared before you can use it (the definition can still come after). So either add a protoype for `fx` and `dif` before `main` or move them before `main`.

Comment: actually no :]
i'm just started cpp 2 weeks ago! but i know the base of defining a function in c# or java ...

Comment: yes that was the point :-]
thank you @crashmstr (Y)

Comment: @user3125076 with regards to C#, this is one of the many differences between it and C++.

Answer (score 1):

Place function declarations

```
double fx (int power,int x);
double dif (int power,int x);
```

before using them.

```
using namespace std;

double fx (int power,int x);
double dif (int power,int x);

int main(){
```

Now your functions are unknown for compiler in place where you are trying to call them.

Answer (score 0):

Any name shall be declared before its using. You are using function name `fx` but you placed its declaration (which at the same time its definition) after the usage of its name. Place before main its declaration

```
double fx (int power,int x);
```

The same is valid relative function `dif`